# How to import XML into a SQL Server database with C# which has parents

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have approximately 100.000 xml files that each contain 1 row of data (but it has 2 parents).

What is the best way to read these XML files, and write the data to a SQL Server table ?

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<recording>
    <dataformat>audio</dataformat>
    <starttime>2015-02-09 08:57:08:000 +0200</starttime>
    <endtime>2015-02-09 08:58:48:000 +0200</endtime>
    <nostart>false</nostart>
    <noend>false</noend>
    <recordingtype>stnbulk</recordingtype>
    <recordingline></recordingline>
    <servicename>005379763634</servicename>
    <servicenumber></servicenumber>
    <deliberatebreak>0</deliberatebreak>
    <calldirection>Outgoing</calldirection>
    <filename>890001000000003.wav</filename>
    <otherinum>0</otherinum>
    <callparty>1</callparty>
    <recordingowners>
        <recordingowner>131</recordingowner>
    </recordingowners>
    <parties>
        <party id="1">
            <number>131</number>
            <name>Santral131</name>
            <pstarttime>2015-02-09 08:58:48:912 +0200</pstarttime>
            <pendtime>2015-02-09 08:58:48:912 +0200</pendtime>
        </party>
        <party id="2">
            <number>005379763634</number>
            <pstarttime>2015-02-09 08:58:48:912 +0200</pstarttime>
            <pendtime>2015-02-09 08:58:48:912 +0200</pendtime>
        </party>
    </parties>
    <guids>
    </guids>
</recording>
```

I tried to read this data by using a `XmlReader` to a Dataset for insert to SQL Server database, but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Maybe try with `XElement` class from `System.Xml.Linq` namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a *one-time-action*? Are the file names easy to list? Does the file's name carry any information? Are all 100k files identically structured?

Please provide the target structure of your tables.

On the first sight, the easiest was to write a *stored procedure*, accepting a paramter of type `XML`.

Your C# application uses `XmlDocument` to read the XML directly from file path and then passes the `OuterXml` to the SP. This SP will read the XML and insert its values into the target tables. Pass this just as string and **do not pass the declaration `<?xml ...?>`**. C# uses unicode implicitly and so does T-SQL-XML...

The following code will give you templates for each type of element how to read it. It should be easy to use something like this within your SP (where `@xml` is the passed in parameter).

**Attention**: However this XML was generated, the contained date-time values do not fullfill the appropriate format  (ISO8601). This needs some tricksing...

Try this within a T-SQL SP:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<recording>
    <dataformat>audio</dataformat>
    <starttime>2015-02-09 08:57:08:000 +0200</starttime>
    <endtime>2015-02-09 08:58:48:000 +0200</endtime>
    <nostart>false</nostart>
    <noend>false</noend>
    <recordingtype>stnbulk</recordingtype>
    <recordingline></recordingline>
    <servicename>005379763634</servicename>
    <servicenumber></servicenumber>
    <deliberatebreak>0</deliberatebreak>
    <calldirection>Outgoing</calldirection>
    <filename>890001000000003.wav</filename>
    <otherinum>0</otherinum>
    <callparty>1</callparty>
    <recordingowners>
        <recordingowner>131</recordingowner>
    </recordingowners>
    <parties>
        <party id="1">
            <number>131</number>
            <name>Santral131</name>
            <pstarttime>2015-02-09 08:58:48:912 +0200</pstarttime>
            <pendtime>2015-02-09 08:58:48:912 +0200</pendtime>
        </party>
        <party id="2">
            <number>005379763634</number>
            <pstarttime>2015-02-09 08:58:48:912 +0200</pstarttime>
            <pendtime>2015-02-09 08:58:48:912 +0200</pendtime>
        </party>
    </parties>
    <guids>
    </guids>
</recording>';
```

--This is the actual query

```
--INSERT INTO YourTargetTable(col1,col2,col3...)
SELECT r.value('(dataformat/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS dataformat
      ,CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(r.value('(starttime/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),11,1,'T'),20,1,'.'),24,1,''),27,0,':'),127) AS starttime
      ,r.value('(nostart/text())[1]','bit') AS nostart
      --more columns
      ,r.value('(recordingowners/recordingowner/text())[1]','bit') AS recordingowner --if there might be more than one, this would need one more call to .nodes()
      ,p.value('@id','int') AS party_id
      ,p.value('(number/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS party_number
      --more columns
FROM @xml.nodes('/recording') AS A(r)
OUTER APPLY A.r.nodes('parties/party') AS B(p)
```

The (partial) result

```
audio   2015-02-09 08:57:08.0000000 +02:00  0   1   1   131
audio   2015-02-09 08:57:08.0000000 +02:00  0   1   2   005379763634
```

**Hint**: If you don't need the time zone, you might use this trick to implicitly add the timezone to the datetime...

```
DECLARE @dtZ DATETIMEOFFSET=CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,'2015-02-09T08:58:48.912+02:00',127);
SELECT (SELECT @dtZ FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','datetime');
```

The result has got the hour `6` now...

```
2015-02-09 06:58:48.913
```

Some background: The ISO8601 format would look like this

```
2015-02-09T08:58:48.9120000+02:00
```

If the strings within the XML were correctly formatted, the reading was done just as easy as any other value. My code uses multiple `STUFF()` calls to correct the format to make it convertible...

Comment: Thanks for your support. This is very useful for my issue.